# In flutter, can i schedule background task by using fixed DateTime?

Tags: flutter, datetime, background-task, flutter-local-notification, flutter-workmanager

Someone please help, I am a fresher and got no one to reach around me.

I am trying to build an app where every day at a **specific time** some task will **execute without the users interaction**.

I tried both **flutter_local_notifications** and **workmanager**.
Problem of the **flutter_local_notifications** is the task won't execute before the user taps on the notification, but I want the execution without user interaction.
Problem with the **workmanager** is it only takes frequency:duration, but I want to use DateTime for a fixed date and time to execute the task.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.